# Insert successfully script not showing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a script that has to do the following thing. After I inserted some data it has to show a message with "Inserted succesfully". It does not work but and I don't know why im inexperienced with Jquery. I have 3 files.

**Script file:**

```
$(document).on("click", ".btnAddSubcat", function(e) {
event.preventDefault();
var subcatvalue = $('.subCat').val();
var subcatprocedure = $('.subProcedure').val();
var url = "../service/functions/postActions.php";
swal({
 title: 'Add a new sub-category?',
 text: "Are you sure to Add this sub-category?",
 type: 'warning',
 showCancelButton: true,
 confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
 cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
 confirmButtonText: 'Yes, Add it!'
}).then(function () {
   $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url : url,
       data: {'subCat': subcatvalue, 'Procedure': subcatprocedure},
       success: function (data) {
           swal({
               title: 'Add!',
               text: "You Add a sub-category!",
               type: 'success',
               confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
               confirmButtonText: 'OK'
           }).then(function () {
              window.location.reload();
           })
        }
     });
  })
});
```

**PHP file**

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputsubcat" class="col-sm-2 control-label">SubCategory:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control subCat" name="subCat" placeholder="...">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputprocedure" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Procedure:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <textarea name="Procedure" rows="8" cols="30" style=" resize: none;" class="form-control subProcedure" placeholder="..."></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label  class="col-sm-2 control-label">Video:</label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <input type="file" name="HWVideo" id="HW-Video" class="form-control uploadVideo" required="true" accept="video/mp4">
                    <video width="450" controls>
                      <source src="mov_bbb.mp4" id="videoLink">
                        Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
                    </video>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class='form-group'>
                <div class='col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10'>
                    <input type='hidden' name='Subcatadd' />
                    <button class='btnAddSubcat btn btn-success glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk' type='submit'></button>
                </div>
            </div>
            </form>
```

**The function file**

```
function AddSubCat() {
$Catid = $_POST['cat-select'];
$Subnaam = $_POST['subCat'];
$procedure = $_POST['Procedure'];
```

and some insert things. that works it just won't show the message. I appreciate your help! It has to be like this

[image: how it has to look]

images before inserting
[image: Before inserting]
after inserting
[image]

Comment: What does the browser console have to say? _Is_ the request actually “successful” (meaning HTTP status code, go check in network panel.)

Comment: it just inserts the data but it doesnt show succesfull

Comment: WHY are you doing this? `window.location.reload();` try commenting it out or use a setTimeout. It is pretty silly to use ajax and then reload the page

Comment: what for is the function AddSubCat()?

Comment: @fmsthird it's my function to insert (but i don't think the rest is neccesay because it inserts well

Comment: When I ask you two rather specific questions to help clarify your problem, do you really think I just want you to repeat what you said already …?

Comment: @04FS it doesn't show anything at all....

Comment: I see. I think better move out your success

Comment: I mean please try this

Comment: oh can't post the code

Comment: it says it is too long

Comment: GO CHECK in the network panel of dev tools, what the actual response to your request is.

Comment: @04FS do you want a screen dump?

Comment: @04FS it gives this `index.php:8 GET https://healthywavez.com/cms/service/assets/css/style.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
index.php:390 GET https://healthywavez.com/cms/service/mov_bbb.mp4 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: Those both have little to do with your AJAX request … go check what the response to _that one_ is in the network panel.

Comment: @04FS i just tested it in edge and there it works

Comment: @04FS i don't really know what you mean by that but it shows that after inserted the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi It might be browser specific. Choose chrome. In case it is on local environment you should avoid Https:// on script CDNs like below.

Comment: i tested it in edge and it works but it won't work in chrome

Comment: Can you please share the screenshot for chrome devTools console .. so that we can help you :)

Comment: i added the screenshots

Comment: Try this it may help you ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40530598/javascript-uncaught-in-promise

Answer (score 1):

I found this

```
$Catid = $_POST['cat-select'];
```

In your AJAX request you have no parameter named cat-select.
Furthermore, you should check whether $_POST and $_GET do actually exist before using them.

Comment: Where does cat-select come from?

Comment: from a dropdown above